# Messaging app (stock) not using full phone number to send text/sms

Tags: sms, 4.2-jelly-bean

I am using Android 4.2 Jelly Bean stock Messaging App and the get "message not sent" error whenever I use my contact to send the message.  I noticed that the Messaging App might not be using the full 10 digit number to send the text/sms.  If I manually enter the full number, e.g., 155551234567 then the message is sent successfully.  But if I use the contact then it only shows in the top display that 123-4567 number and then it will fail to send any text/sms.

I am wondering if that is problem and if so how can I set the Messaging App to use the full phone number?  I did not find any setting for this anywhere so far.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're talking about US numbers? If you haven't tried including a `+` at the start of numbers saved in your contacts that could be worth doing. `+1 555 123 4567` is the international format and may help other apps know where to send your message/call.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I replied early but don't see it here.  So am doing again.  I already have full phone numbers.